# Windows Updates not downloading when set to Download Only

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, windows-update

I am running Windows server 2016, with Windows Updates set to Download Only, however when I run the following script, it shows all outstanding updates as not downloaded, how do I investigate why they are not downloading in the background?

```
$updatesession =  [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session"))
$updatesearcher = $updatesession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$searchresult = $updatesearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")
$searchresult
```

Comment: Please don't cross-duplicate posts on Stack Exchange websites; this is a cross-site duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432161/3482140!

Comment: I have voted to close that one, as it should of been on here and now on stack overflow

Comment: As for your comment on the other post, yes there are files in C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download. But windows GUI does not state that they have been downloaded!

Comment: Windows GUI only says "Updates are ready to be installed" at the bottom of the list of updates available.

Comment: Please check WindowsUpdate.log. You can run Get-WindowsUpdateLog cmdlet in powershell - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsupdate/get-windowsupdatelog?view=win10-ps